# elasticsearch setup on Gcloud VM fails

Tags: elasticsearch, virtual-machine, gcloud

I wish to run my elasticsearch remotely on gcloud VM, this is configured to run at 127.0.0.1 at a specific port 9200. How to access this from a website outside this vm? If I change the network host to 0.0.0.0 on the yml file, even 9200 port becomes inaccessible. How do I overcome this problem?

```
Changed network.host: [_site_ , _local_ , _global_ ]
_site_ = internal ip given by google cloud vm, 
_local_ = 127.0.0.1, 
_global_ = found using curl ifconfig.me, 
Opened a specific port (9200) and tried to connect with global IP address.

curl to the global ip gives 
>Output: Failed to connect to (_global_ ip) port 9200: connection refused.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by going through the logs and found out that the public ip address is re-mapped to the internal ip address, hence network.host can't be set to external ip directly. Elasticsearch yml config is as follows:

1. **'network.host: xx.xx.xxx.xx'** is set to the internal ip (given by google),
2. **'http.cors.enabled: true'**,
3. **'http.cors.allow-origin:"*"**, (Do not use * in production, its a security issue)
4. **'discovery.type: single-node'** in my case to make it work independently and not in a cluster

Now this sandboxed version can be accessed from outside the VM using the external IP address given by Google.

Answer (score 0):

So put network.host:0.0.0.0 and then try to allow 9200 and 9201 port and restart the elasticsearch service.If you are using ubuntu then `sudo service elasticsearch restart` then check by doing `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200?pretty'`.Let me know if you are still facing any issues.

Comment: The same problem persists if I use network.host as 0.0.0.0

Comment: We are using the same configuration and it is working fine.So check the logs in var/lib/elasticsearch/logs.

Comment: @siddeshwar-raghavan please use your ipAddress  at network.host:10.21.xx.xxx , this should work.

Comment: Still not working for me, I have tried everything mentioned.

Comment: If you can share the yml file it would be of great help.

Comment: Yes we can help you out

Comment: @KARTHEEKGUMMALURI I made some changes and now it didn't fail in the vm with network host set to 0.0.0.0. While accessing from outside, the connection is not made. What ip address should I use while accessing from outside the vm?

Comment: U need to put public ip to the network.host.Then it will work from outside.You need to give upvote for me if it works for you .... Thanks

Comment: Config for Elasticsearch running on Google VM its a little different. Google maps the external ip to the internal one (checked in logs). Hence, you've to use the internal ip with network host and use the external ip while accessing it from outside the VM. Therefore, just putting the public ip at the network host will not help. Thanks. Also, I don't have enough reputation to upvote :P

Answer (score 0):

Use following configurations for `elasticsearch.yml`

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
action.auto_create_index: false
index.mapper.dynamic: false
```